# How to convert date to words in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I have a date displayed in HTML. The date is currently displayed as `2012-03-12`. So now, I want to display this date as words i.e it should be displayed as `12 March 2012`. Below is the HTML code I used.

```
<tr>
  <th>Date of Birth: </th>
  <td>{{dob}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here, `dob` contains the value that has to be converted to words. How can I do this?

Comment: you would need to use a little bit of javascript here. see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: What are you using to pick the date?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely with the wonderful [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/).

```
dob = moment(dob).format('DD MMMM YYYY');
```

Answer (score 3):

If your date is an instance of `Date`then you can try something like this

```
var dob = new Date('3/12/2012');
var dobArr = dob.toDateString().split(' ');
var dobFormat = dobArr[2] + ' ' + dobArr[1] + ' ' + dobArr[3];
```

This would make `dobFormat` `12 Mar 2012`
(if you want it to say `March` couple this with what Rhyono has suggested).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use any library and want to take a date like your initial one and change it, it can be done like this:

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

function convertDate(date_str) {
  temp_date = date_str.split("-");
  return temp_date[2] + " " + months[Number(temp_date[1]) - 1] + " " + temp_date[0];
}
console.log(convertDate("2012-03-12"));
```

Comment: I'm new to Javascript . Can you tell me how to call the above function inside my <tr> tags

Answer (score 1):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), and it will be a snap.

```
moment(dob).format('DD MMMM YYYY')
```

Comment: so much dependency on libs :|

Comment: Neither @CWSpear or I meant that you print this out literally. Rather, you pass the string in `dob` to `moment` as shown and store the output in a template variable to display in the `td` cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)** library which extents Date object.